# Examples of CAT(0)-groups

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, alexandrov-geometry

My question is the following:

Let M be a simply connected Riemannian manifold whose sectional curvatures
are all nonpositive and let G be a group. Suppose that G acts in M properly discontinuous and
cocompactly by isometries. Is G a CAT(0) group?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is yes, since $M$ is a $CAT(0)$ space, and the group is quasi-isometric to it. See (for example) Jim Cannon's article in Bedford Keane Series:

The theory of negatively curved spaces and groups
J Cannon - t. Bedford, M. Keane, and C. Series. Oxford University …, 1991

Comment: By definition, a group is $CAT(0)$ if it acts isometrically, properly and co-compactly on a $CAT(0)$ space... So it is enough to say that $M$ is $CAT(0)$. See http://www.aimath.org/pggt/Hyperbolic_and_CAT%280%29_Groups?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=bridson-version1.pdf

Comment: Igor, you should say "yes by definition", but not "yes, since".

Comment: @ε-δ: I believe that is the essence of Alain's commentary...

Comment: To be fair, it is not a trivial fact that a simply connected Riemannian manifold whose sectional curvatures are all nonpositive is CAT(0).

Comment: @Anon: I believe that this is why the T is in CAT(0)...